# Vue without root element

Tags: vue.js

How implement a component that doesn't output a root element, like the [vuetify tooltip](https://vuetifyjs.com/ja/components/tooltips/) or [And design](https://antdv.com/components/tooltip/), in vue 2.x? And perhaps it's not a functional component.

```html
<my-tooltip text="Tooltip">
  <my-button>Button</my-button>
<my-tooltip>
```

to

```html
<my-button>Button</my-button>
<div class="tooltip">Tooltip></div>
```

I don't have the skills to fully parse the vuetify source.
I would appreciate it if you could show me a simple demo.

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 2, you have to have only one root element whereas it's not required in Vue 3. You can wrap your html in a div or a v-container or whatever:

```
<v-container>
    <my-button>Button</my-button>
    <div class="tooltip">Tooltip></div>
</v-container>
```

Comment: Or you might want to use a plain div to make sure it doesn't affect your current layout

Comment: Year I know that, but the vuetify tooltip (vue 2.x) doesn't output a root element.